# Firebase storage Upload file -python

Tags: python, firebase, storage, firebase-storage

I need some help
I am using python 3.6 to upload a file to firebase storage, but I couldn't get a reasonable result .

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, storage

cred=credentials.Certificate('C:\\Users\\blackturtle\\Envs\\tube\\ps.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': 'gs://dene-2ac17.appspot.com'
})
db = firestore.client()
bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob('hello.txt')
outfile='C:\\Users\\blackturtle\\Envs\\tube\\hello.txt'
blob.upload_from_filename(outfile)
```

That code gives this error below

```
Exception has occurred: google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound
404 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/gs://dene-2ac17.appspot.com/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
  File "C:\Users\blackturtle\Envs\tube\drive.py", line 27, in <module>
    blob.upload_from_filename(outfile)
```

When I change and use this code below to upload file

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, storage

cred=credentials.Certificate('C:\\Users\\blackturtle\\Envs\\tube\\ps.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': 'gs://dene-2ac17.appspot.com'
})
db = firestore.client()
bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob('hello.txt')
outfile='C:\\Users\\blackturtle\\Envs\\tube\\hello.txt'
with open(outfile, 'rb') as my_file:
    blob.upload_from_file(my_file)
```

Got this error

```
Exception has occurred: google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound
404 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/gs://dene-2ac17.appspot.com/o?uploadType=resumable: ('Response headers must contain header', 'location')
  File "C:\Users\blackturtle\Envs\tube\drive.py", line 29, in <module>
    blob.upload_from_file(my_file)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing `'gs://dene-2ac17.appspot.com'` with `'dene-2ac17.appspot.com'` as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start?lang=en).

> **Use a default bucket**
>
> You can specify a default bucket name when
>   initializing the Admin SDK. Then you can retrieve an authenticated
>   reference to this bucket. The bucket name must not contain gs:// or
>   any other protocol prefixes. For example, if the bucket URL displayed
>   in the Firebase Console is gs://bucket-name.appspot.com, pass the
>   string bucket-name.appspot.com to the Admin SDK.

Comment: Thanks for advice.I have just tried what you suggested but got the sama error   ('Response headers must contain header', 'location') any advice will be appreciated @Cheche

Comment: Ouch!, thought it would work. Was that error on your first or second code?,

Comment: I tried both code block seperately again as you suggested way and they gave the errors as same as above . @Cheche

Comment: Ok, sorry @digging - Last two shots: a) try isolating your problem removing `db = firestore.client()`; b) check your credentials are right.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time for problem @Cheche are it is all about credendials problem.I copied credentials from firebase and pasted then it works like charm.Thank you again

Comment: @digging great!!, glad to know.